# No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8082

Tags: c#, sockets, localhost, tcplistener

I have made a small windows service which i needs to get connected from my own localhost system but on running the application i am getting error as..

```
No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it 127.0.0.1:8082
```

whereas it is perfectly working in Live ip and port numbers but i need to test it on localhost as i cant access the live running ip everytime..

Here is my code...

```
byte[] data = new byte[1024];
         string input, stringData;
         String ip = "127.0.0.1";
         Int32 port = 8082;
         string path = "D:\\";

            if (File.Exists("ipsettings.txt"))
            {
                File.Delete("ipsettings.txt");
            }
            IPAddress ipad = IPAddress.Parse(ip);
            IPEndPoint ipend = new IPEndPoint(ipad, port);
            Socket sock = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            try
            {
                sock.Connect(ipend);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

I am getting error at this point..

```
 try
            {
                sock.Connect(ipend);

            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
```

Please help me to resolve the issue..
Thanks in advance..

Comment: Ask your server what it's problem is?

Comment: @MartinJames sir this is localhost and my application type is windows service running in debug mode

Comment: "Actively refused" sounds like a firewall issue.

Comment: @Floris how to correct it sir

Comment: Look at the firewall software / utility you use on your machine. Unplug from the internet, then turn off all protection. See if the problem goes away. If it does, add a rule to allow this connection. For more help add details of what you find in the question. Remember to turn firewall back on before reconnecting to internet!!!

Comment: @Floris still the problem persists..

Comment: The regular Windows firewall normally doesn't affect localhost connections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> whereas it is perfectly working in Live ip and port numbers

How do you know that? The error says the exact opposite. Noone is listening at that IP:port. Run tcpview from the sysinternals suite to know more. Note that listening on the machine's own IP address, like 192.168.55.55, and listening on 127.0.0.1, and listening on * (every address) are different things. When you connect to 127.0.0.1, it would connect successfully to the latter two, but not the first. It could also go wrong if the other end is listening on UDP, not TCP.

Comment: I would rather believe in the error message :). It says noone is listening, then noone is listening.

Comment: @Adi with `netstat -a` on the command line you can check if a service is listening on a port. For your connection there should be a line like `TCP  127.0.0.1:8082 (...) LISTENING` or `TCP  0.0.0.0:8082 (...) LISTENING`. If there is only something like `TCP  192.168.55.5:8082 (...) LISTENING` (to take @fejesjoco's example) the service binds to a specific interface. Ask then your team for help ...